# SUM de campo de duas Subconsultas em MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

Estou precisando de um campo derivado de duas subconsultas que dê a somatória de valores baseado num campo. Segue exemplo:

SQL:

```
SELECT
    CodCliente
    ,DataVenda
    ,Vendedor
    ,Valor
    ,DataPagamento
    ,TotalCliente --> SOMA DE [Valor] de mesmo [CodCliente]

FROM

    ((SELECT
        CodCliente
        ,DataVenda
        ,Vendedor = 'Fulano'
        ,Valor
        ,DataPagamento

    FROM TabelaVendasFulano)

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT
        CodCliente
        ,DataVenda
        ,Vendedor = 'Ciclano'
        ,Valor
        ,DataPagamento

    FROM TabelaVendasCiclano)) Vendas
```

Um exemplo do resultado que quero:

```
+------------+-----------+----------+-------+---------------+--------------+
| CodCliente | DataVenda | Vendedor | Valor | DataPagamento | TotalCliente |
+------------+-----------+----------+-------+---------------+--------------+
|     01     |2014-01-02 |  Fulano  | 25,00 |  2014-01-05   |    105,00    |
|     01     |2014-02-07 |  Fulano  | 50,00 |  2014-02-10   |    105,00    |
|     01     |2014-02-16 |  Ciclano | 30,00 |  2014-02-20   |    105,00    |
|     02     |2014-01-20 |  Fulano  | 15,00 |  2014-01-25   |     70,00    |
|     02     |2014-03-05 |  Fulano  | 55,00 |  2014-03-10   |     70,00    |
|     03     |2014-03-12 |  Ciclano | 80,00 |  2014-03-20   |    140,00    |
|     03     |2014-07-25 |  Ciclano | 60,00 |  2014-07-30   |    140,00    |
+------------+-----------+----------+-------+---------------+--------------+
```

Quero saber como fazer essa coluna TotalCliente utilizando o SQL que fiz, que nada mais é que a soma do campo `[Valor]` das duas Subconsultas baseado no campo `[CodCliente]`

Eu sei que existem maneiras bem mais simples de resolver isso nesse exemplo, mas usei apenas para ilustrar. Estou utilizando SQL Server.

Obrigado!

Comment: É SQL Server amigo?

Comment: Opa, é sim.. Esqueci de especificar.

Comment: Você pode [edit] sua pergunta e incluir a tag para facilitar nas buscas do google.

Comment: É no SQL Server 2008 é mais chatinho de fazer o que você quer rs

Comment: Como faria no 2012, por curiosidade? (Não vai resolver meu problema, mas é bom saber)

Comment: Seria algo com [PARTITION BY ... OVER](http://www.midnightdba.com/Jen/2010/10/tip-over-and-partition-by/) (Calma ai, parece que vai funcionar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar [OVER(PARTITION BY ... )](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms189461%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) na sua query para isso:

```
SELECT
    CodCliente
    ,DataVenda
    ,Vendedor
    ,Valor
    ,DataPagamento
    ,SUM(Valor) As TotalCliente OVER (PARTITION BY CodCliente)

FROM

    ((SELECT
        CodCliente
        ,DataVenda
        ,Vendedor = 'Fulano'
        ,Valor
        ,DataPagamento

    FROM TabelaVendasFulano)

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT
        CodCliente
        ,DataVenda
        ,Vendedor = 'Ciclano'
        ,Valor
        ,DataPagamento

    FROM TabelaVendasCiclano)) Vendas
```

Nos casos de uma consulta como a sua, gosto de usar uma [CTE (Common Table Expression)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms175972.aspx)

```
WITH Vendas AS 
(SELECT
    CodCliente
    ,DataVenda
    ,Vendedor = 'Fulano'
    ,Valor
    ,DataPagamento    
FROM TabelaVendasFulano)

UNION ALL

(SELECT
    CodCliente
    ,DataVenda
    ,Vendedor = 'Ciclano'
    ,Valor
    ,DataPagamento
)

SELECT
    CodCliente
    ,DataVenda
    ,Vendedor
    ,Valor
    ,DataPagamento
    ,SUM(Valor) AS TotalCliente OVER (PARTITION BY CodCliente)
```

Comment: Como só fui saber dessa função agora!? Sensacional!
Obrigado!